# How to integrate Facebook login data

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I'm trying to add Facebook login for our site. I can authenticate a user with Facebook and it returns a token (which is short lived). I can also upgrade that token to a longer timed one (but only lasts a couple of months).

What should I be storing in our database to authenticate against our user data? Is it safe enough to just rely on the Facebook userid or do I need to store the token as well? If I store the token in the database how can I make sure that this is still valid when a user comes to login again (especially if it's not for another few months)?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems token should only be used when making opengraph calls and not for authentication. It is safe enough to rely on the userid returned by the SDK (once the session has been validated) to authenticate.